# Duplicate local webpages in different locations grab same localStorage data?

Tags: html, google-chrome, local-storage

I have a folder structure (an extracted zip file) with a file in it called "config.html" that calls `localStorage` when it loads.  If I unzip an instance of this folder structure to the desktop, launch "config.html," generate some data that gets saved to `localStorage`, and then extract another instance of the zip file anywhere else on my hard drive, and open the secondary "config.html", that `localStorage` call brings in the `localStorage` data from the *first* instance of "config.html", regardless of location on my hard drive. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or it's a limitation with `localStorage` when used locally.  It seems that when retrieving data, the `localStorage` call looks for a webpage name, and not the entire folder path as I was expecting.  Also, if I call `localStorage.clear()`, it clears data for all instances of "config.html."  Essentially, all webpages with the same file name seem to be tied to the same `localStorage` saved data.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) and [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) are unique per origin - that is protocol, host and port combined.

> Two pages have the same origin if the protocol, port (if one is
>   specified), and host are the same for both pages.

**Source:** [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Since you are running it locally (just opening the HTML file) without a server with varying protocol, host or port, it's all one origin, hence the shared data. The path difference is irrelevant